# Cypress - How to redirect without opening a new window

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a cypress test that on clicking a button the system redirects to a new window.
I've tried some solutions (invoke,stub) without success.

I need to do some testing but I need it to always be redirected on the same screen as cypress doesn't support multiple windows.

My button code:

```
<button id="cmdEnviar" name="cmdEnviar" type="button" onclick="TrPage._autoSubmit('_id5','cmdEnviar',event,1);return false;" class="x7j">Enviar</button>
```

My code:

```
it('register new user', function() {
        cy.visit('/')  
        cy.get('#txtLogin').type(Cypress.env('login'))
        cy.get('#txtSenha').type(Cypress.env('pass'))
        cy.get('#btnEnviar').click()
        cy.get('#cmbSistemas').select(11)
        cy.get('#cmdEnviar').click() //here is the button
    
        //here is redirected to another window 
        cy.contains('Colaborador').click()
        cy.contains('Cadastro').click()
       
    })
```

Could anyone help me, if there is any solution?

Comment: Is it a new window or a modal?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without seeing what your onclick event actually does, I can't recommend a strategy for validating the behavior of onclick is functioning as intended.

Instead, we can validate that the button has the correct `onclick` attribute value.

```js
...
cy.get('#cmdEnviar')
  .should('have.attr', 'onclick', "TrPage._autoSubmit('_id5','cmdEnviar',event,1);return false;");
...
```

Comment: My event on click :



 function onclick(event) {
  TrPage._autoSubmit('_id5', 'cmdEnviar', event, 1);
  return false;
}

Comment: Right, that's not enough information to go off of to figure out what that's actually doing when it launches the new window.

Comment: Agoff,

I don't want to validate what it does after the button, I want to continue with my test scenario, but I need to go through this part.

Comment: Then the validation I've added above should work. It validates that the button has an `onclick` attribute equal to what you've added.